# setOnKeyListner Argument

Tags: android, arguments

I'm trying a "to-do list" app that is found in a book.

the next error appear to me and I don't know what is the solution

```
The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnKeyListener(){})
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
```

Add this line, and you will be able to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I read the same book. It seems that it is an old book. any way i think i found the solution although it is still not working:
in addition to the line:

import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;

add:

```
    myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
                {
                    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }

            return false;
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your listener should implement [`View.OnKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html), not `OnKeyListener`.

If it is an anonymous class inside the method, it should be:

```
myView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you complete the code,you can pressed "CTRL+Shift+O"(Organize Imports Dialog pop),and choose the "android.view.View.OnKeyListener",hope to help you ！